# $\Delta$-complex structure on the Möbius band

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Find a $\Delta$-complex structure on the space $X$ Möbius band, and calculate the homology groups $H_n^{\Delta}(X)$.

I am struggling to solve this problem. How can we come up with a $\Delta-$complex structure for this space?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what are you stuck on?

Comment: @anomaly The Mobius band is a square with a set of opposite edges identified in reverse direction. I don't know how to triangulate this square to come up with $2$-simplices.

Comment: Right, but what specific problem are you running into when constructing the triangulation? The Moebius band is a quotient of a rectangle; choose a $\Delta$-complex structure that behaves nicely under that quotient map.

Comment: unless I'm mistaken, you should be able to do this with two $0$-simplicies, four $1$-simplices, and two $2$-simplices.

Comment: Forget the Möbius band for a bit. Can you find any $\Delta$-complex structure on a square?